# Not able to use cx-media component with a media container

Tags: javascript, angular, spartacus-storefront

Below codes on Spartacus version 2.0 work fine.
the template file:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  <cx-media [container]="data.media" [title]="data | json"></cx-media>
</ng-container>
```

the ts file:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-banner',
  templateUrl: './custom-banner.component.html',
})
export class CustomBannerComponent {

  data$: Observable<CmsBannerComponent> = this.componentData.data$;

  constructor(protected componentData: CmsComponentData<CmsBannerComponent>) {}

}
```

But it's not compiling on spartacus version 4 and giving below errors.

```
Type 'CmsBannerComponentMedia | CmsResponsiveBannerComponentMedia | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MediaContainer'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MediaContainer'.ngtsc(2322)

Error: src/app/spartacus/features/custom-cms-components/custom-banner/custom-banner.component.html:3:14 - error TS2322: Type 'CmsBannerComponentMedia | CmsResponsiveBannerComponentMedia | undefined' is not assignable to type 'MediaContainer'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MediaContainer'.

3   <cx-media [container]="data.media" [title]="data | json"></cx-media>
               ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/spartacus/features/custom-cms-components/custom-banner/custom-banner.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './custom-banner.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component CustomBannerComponent.
```

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding libraries with `yarn build:libs`?

Comment: No, I was using the Spartacus libs from the npm site, and I believe this is the recommended way to use the libs off-the-shelf in a project. But you are right, I should give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

I reproduced the issue and created [a bug ticket](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/issues/15013). You can observe it, and update your project when it will be done and released.

For now, I can suggest only ugly workarounds like:

- locally use $any(...): `[container]="$any(data.media)"`
- or globally change the flag:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictTemplates": false
  }
```